# Is there any way increasing the JVM heap memory can lead to performance issue

Tags: performance, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

our system started giving performance issues recently. but the changes are only switching from logback to log4j and increasing JVM heap memory from 4GB to 8GB. but it started giving performance issues after this deployment and GC is not happening.

Comment: Could you please elaborate `GC is not happening`? JVM always runs GC (I assume you are not using [Epsilon GC](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/epsilon-the-jdks-do-nothing-garbage-collector)). But the GC may not free memory as there may be a memory leak in your code. What are exactly those performance issues?

Comment: I am not using Epsilon GC  as my JDK version is 1.8.  before when the memory size was 4GB, I verified in the JVM metrics after every 3 to 4 days GC was happening when the memory size was reaching 3 GB. But now I am not seeing the same behavior the heap size is continuously growing and we ended up doing a restart at some point when the performance issue is getting started. The service response time is increasing usually it takes less than one second but at some time it is even taking 10 seconds.